# Zend Framework 2 - bjyauthorize 403 Forbidden

Tags: zend-framework2

when I install ZfUser,bjyauthorize => with ZfUser module it's work correctly but when I acced in all other module ex : Application module I have this :

> 403 Forbidden You are not authorized to access home.

In module.bjyauthorize.global I use this :

```
<?php

return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(

        // set the 'guest' role as default (must be defined in a role provider)
        'default_role' => 'guest',

        /* this module uses a meta-role that inherits from any roles that should
         * be applied to the active user. the identity provider tells us which
         * roles the "identity role" should inherit from.
         *
         * for ZfcUser, this will be your default identity provider
         */
        'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb',

        /* role providers simply provide a list of roles that should be inserted
         * into the Zend\Acl instance. the module comes with two providers, one
         * to specify roles in a config file and one to load roles using a
         * Zend\Db adapter.
         */
        'role_providers' => array(

            /* here, 'guest' and 'user are defined as top-level roles, with
             * 'admin' inheriting from user
             */
            'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config' => array(
                'guest' => array(),
                'user'  => array('children' => array(
                    'admin' => array(),
                )),
            ),

            // this will load roles from the user_role table in a database
            // format: user_role(role_id(varchar), parent(varchar))
            'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb' => array(
                'table'             => 'user_role',
                'role_id_field'     => 'role_id',
                'parent_role_field' => 'parent',
            ),
        ),

        // resource providers provide a list of resources that will be tracked
        // in the ACL. like roles, they can be hierarchical
        'resource_providers' => array(
            'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
                'admin' => array(),
                //'pants' => array(),
            ),
        ),

        /* rules can be specified here with the format:
         * array(roles (array), resource, [privilege (array|string), assertion])
         * assertions will be loaded using the service manager and must implement
         * Zend\Acl\Assertion\AssertionInterface.
         * *if you use assertions, define them using the service manager!*
         */
        'rule_providers' => array(
            'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config' => array(
                'allow' => array(
                    // allow guests and users (and admins, through inheritance)
                    // the "wear" privilege on the resource "pants"
                    //array(array('guest', 'user'), 'wear', 'pants'),
                    array(array('admin'), 'admin'),
                ),

                // Don't mix allow/deny rules if you are using role inheritance.
                // There are some weird bugs.
                'deny' => array(
                    // ...
                ),
            ),
        ),

        /* Currently, only controller and route guards exist
         */
        'guards' => array(
            /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled), it will block
             * access to all controllers and actions unless they are specified here.
             * You may omit the 'action' index to allow access to the entire controller
             */
            'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array()),
            //backend
            array('controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index','roles' => array('guest','user','admin')),
            array('controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Annonces', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            array('controller' => 'Annonces\Controller\Annonces', 'roles' => array('guest','user','admin')),

        ),

        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route' => array(
            //array('route' => 'annonces', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => array('guest')),                
            array('route' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest','user')),
            array('route' => 'annonce', 'roles' => array('guest','user','admin')),
            array('route' => 'annonces', 'roles' => array('guest','user','admin')),
        ),
        ),
    ),

);
```

Comment: Your missing the access permission for the `home` route (e.g `array('route' => 'home', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user'))`). Also decide if you want to use controller *OR* route guards, don't use both.

Comment: it's work !!! think you :)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to pick an ACL strategy. The config file that is provided shows you all the available options but that doesn't mean you should use all of them.

With your role_providers, you should either use a db connection or use specify the array. Mine looks like the following (applicable if you are using doctrine) -

```
'role_providers' => array(
    'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => array(
        'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
        'role_entity_class' => 'User\Entity\Role',
    ),
),
```

For simple applications, you don't need to specify rule_providers & resource_providers. I tend to specify them when I am using it for menus

I noticed that you are using two guards. You should only use one guard i.e. either a route guard or a controller guard. I personally tend to use the controller guard more as you can have multiple routes for one controller. An example of what a controller guard might look like is as follows -

```
return array(
    ...
    'guards' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array(
                 'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                 'action' => array(
                     'index', // for indexAction
                 ),
                 'roles' => array(
                     'guest',
                     'user',
                 ),
             ),
             array(
                 'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                 'action' => array(
                     'login', // for loginAction
                     'authenticate', 
                 ),
                 'roles' => array(
                     'guest',
                 ),
             ),
             array(
                 'controller' => 'zfcuser',
                 'action' => array(
                     'changepassword',
                     'changeemail',
                     'logout',
                 ),
                 'roles' => array(
                     'user',
                 ),
             ),
             ....
```

I would also highly suggest you go through this tutorial -

http://samminds.com/2013/03/zfcuser-bjyauthorize-and-doctrine-working-together/

While this tutorial uses Doctrine, the concepts applies to Zend/DB